# Importing a fortran dll in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fortran, dllimport

I am having trouble importing my `dllwrap`-ed Fortran code into C#. I am really working on something a bit more complicated than the example I'm showing here but I want to make the simple example work, and then tackle the full-scale problem. I'm working with MinGW and MSYS.

Here is my fortran code, in the file MyThreeDll.f:

```
  integer function three()
     three = 3
     return
  end function
```

Then I ran `gfortran -c MyThreeDll.f` with the expected output of one MyThreeDll.o file. The next command I ran was
`dllwrap --export-all-symbols MyThreeDll.o -gfortran -o MyThreeDll.dll`
and get a dll-file. This I then move into the folder of my C# console project in Visual Studio 2010, and add to the project (it will absolutely not let me add it as a reference) and I try to run it. Then this happens.

[image: Screencap of my Visual Studio setup]

I've tried making the dll with `gfortran -shared`, but it didn't help. Adding underscores before and / or after the function name doesn't help either. So now I'm stuck, because this is as far as google has led me.

Comment: Select the DLL in the solution explorer window and set its Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if newer".

Comment: Put the dll in that very folder where your exe file is.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. That coupled with renaming the function to `three_()` did the trick. Post as an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll skip.  I don't want to answer your next question.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh well :) But I believe I have the gist of it. Next I'll try a few subroutines with different input types. Then I think I've figured out what needs to be figured out, and I'll ready to do this with ARPACK (I already have the dll, and I'm beginning to understand the example codes that came with the package well enough to implement them in C#).

Comment: I would really suggest you to use modern Fortran-C interoperability `bind(C)` and `iso_c_binding`. You can then forget the name mangling by different compilers (which is much worse when you use modules).

Comment: @VladimirF That seems like a nice and smooth approach. However, the fortran package I'm hoping to utilize with this approach doesn't use it, and I'm not about to change hundreds of fully functional fortran routines so that it's slightly more convenient for me to use them. Also, there aren't modules in the package, so I hope I'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments from @HansPassant solved my problem. For posterity I should add that if I run the `dllwrap` command with the option `--output-def MyThreeDll.def` in addition to all the other stuff, I will get a .def text file containing the resulting name of the function, namely `three_()`, rather than `three()`.

This is something dllwrap does with the help from gfortran, apparently, and it can allegedly be changed with options, although I have neither the energy or the need to look for how.